# Decomposition space and quotient topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

This question is from Exercise 5.1 of Wayne Patty's topology.

> Let (X,T) be a $T_1$ space and let (D,U) be a decomposition space of X. Prove that (D,U) is $T_1$ iff each member of D is a closed subset of X.

The following definition might be useful:Let(X,T) be a topological space and let D be a partition of X. Define a function $p: X \to D$ as follows: For each $x\in X$ , p(x) is the member of D that contains x. If U is the quotient topology on D induced by p, then (D,U) is a quotient space of X. The function p is called natural map of X onto D. The set D is also called a decomposition of X and the quotient space (D,U) is also called a decomposition space.

> Attempt for this question: Let (D,U) is $T_1$ , then for each distinct x,y in X there exists disjoint open sets such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ and x doesn't lies in V and y doesn't lies in U .

Why must each member of D be a closed subset of X? I have no idea why it must hold true and what result I should use. Also ,I couldn't make any progress while proving the converse.

The problem is that I am very bad in questions related to Quotient Topology although I have read theory from Wayne Patty but still I need help in solving such problems.

So, can you please help in this question?

Comment: Recall that a member of $D$ is a *point* of the decomposition space. And $T_1$ = every singleton is closed. $(X,T)$ need not be $T_1$ BTW, that's a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the book contains this characterization of $T_1$-spaces: one-point sets are closed.
Thus "$F$ is closed in $D$ is closed iff $p^{-1}[F]$ is closed in $X$" should make the problem doable.